# Delete duplicate values in a sql row via a php script?

Tags: php, mysql

Well I have this script that deletes tokens if the tokens expired or is bad. My old friend made it and I don't have his contact anymore. I want to improve it by having able to delete duplicate values in the column token as well.

```
try {
    $database = new PDO("mysql:host={$db['host']};dbname={$db['name']}", $db['user'], $db['pass']);
    $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function check_token($token){
    $headers = get_headers("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={$token}");
    if($headers[0] == "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" or $headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$tokens = $database->query("SELECT * FROM pinodex_autoliker");
$bad_tokens = 0;
foreach($tokens as $row){
    if(!check_token($row['token'])){
        $token = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM pinodex_autoliker WHERE token = :token");
        $token->execute(
            array(
                "token" => $row['token']
            )
        );
        $bad_tokens++;
    }
}
header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo "TOKEN CLEAN DONE! REMOVED {$bad_tokens} BAD TOKENS FROM THE DATABASE.";
exit;
```

Comment: it seems you have delete problem ?

Comment: @Noman It's only deleting bad and expired tokens but not the duplicate values.

Comment: please add the data from `pinodex_autoliker` table in question with create table query

Comment: only id and token columns

Comment: might be a variable scope issue. Try `function check_token($database,$token)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- it gave me this error `Warning: Missing argument 2 for check_token(), called in /home/thestash/public_html/clean_test.php on line 27 and defined in /home/thestash/public_html/clean_test.php on line 15`

Comment: try adding to `if(!check_token($database,$row['token']))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- didnt remove any tokens. hmm

Comment: pretty sure now that you need to add a `where` clause to `"SELECT * FROM pinodex_autoliker"` same as you did for the delete. ` WHERE token = :token` then use the same method. should work

Comment: Got this error after I adding WHERE token = :token lke you said.
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':token' at line 1' in /home/thestash/public_html/clean_test.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /home/thestash/public_html/clean_test.php(24): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM t...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/thestash/public_html/clean_test.php on line 24`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pure SQL approach for this, which will delete duplicates in 1 SQL Query

This will delete all rows , if row`s id is not smallest for this token

```
 DELETE FROM pinodex_autoliker WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT * FROM ( select min(pa.id) from pinodex_autoliker pa group by token ) pa2 )
```

The result of both queries should be the same.

I think its better than selecting duplicate rows , importing it into php , then executing delete query for each id , imagine if there are 100000 bad tokens , you have to execute 100000 back and forth for nothing.

Comment: Will this work as an update for Noman's code? So one record will be kept after deleting the duplicates?

Comment: yes , the record with the smallest ID wont be deleted , you can test it yourself

Comment: I tried your 2nd approach but it gives me this error
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 Table 'pinodex_autoliker' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data' in /home/thestash/public_html/testes.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /home/thestash/public_html/testes.php(51): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/thestash/public_html/testes.php on line 51`

Comment: hm , try adding alias , I have updated my answer , what about the first query ?

Comment: 1st one has errors similar to this, i'm not sure what's wrong..

2nd approach update gives this;
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 Table 'pinodex_autoliker' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data' in /home/thestash/public_html/dup_token.exec.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /home/thestash/public_html/dup_token.exec.php(51): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/thestash/public_html/dup_token.exec.php on line 51`

Comment: bro maybe im putting it in the wrong place? is this the correct place to put it?
`$smt = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM pinodex_autoliker WHERE id NOT IN ( select min(pa.id) from pinodex_autoliker pa group by token )")`

Comment: Yes you are setting it in correct place , I have tested an updated my query , it works 100% , please try one more time

Answer (score 1):

For delete duplicate tokens you need to write query using `COUNT` and `Group by`.

```
select id,count(token) as tokenCount,token from pinodex_autoliker group by token
```

then Loop through the output with `DELETE` Query.

```
foreach($recordSet as $rs) { 

$token = $rs['token'];

  $smt = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM pinodex_autoliker WHERE token = :token");
    $smt->execute(
        array(
            ":token" => $token
        )
    );

}
```

Above query will give you output like:

```
id  tokenCount  token
2   2           325gqsdgrgrqgrgrg
1   2           3b3kj4b31jbj421b431fdsafdfdfs
4   1           n3rlk3nrkl213nrk1nrk1rk
```

[**SQL Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/620ab/5)

For adding delete duplicate token code.

```
try {
    $database = new PDO("mysql:host={$db['host']};dbname={$db['name']}", $db['user'], $db['pass']);
    $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function check_token($token)
{
    $headers = get_headers("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={$token}");
    if ($headers[0] == "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" or $headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$tokens = $database->query("SELECT * FROM pinodex_autoliker");
$bad_tokens = 0;
foreach ($tokens as $row) {
    if (!check_token($row['token'])) {
        $token = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM pinodex_autoliker WHERE token = :token");
        $token->execute(
            array(
                ":token" => $row['token']
            )
        );
        $bad_tokens++;
    }
}


// Delete duplicate tokens
$duplicatetokens = $database->query("select id,count(token) as tokenCount,token from pinodex_autoliker group by token");
$duplicate_tokens = 0;

foreach ($duplicatetokens as $dprow) {
    $tokenCol = $dprow['token'];
    $tokenCount = $dprow['tokenCount'];
    if ($tokenCount > 1) {
        $smt = $database->prepare("DELETE FROM pinodex_autoliker WHERE token = :token");
        $smt->execute(
            array(
                ":token" => $tokenCol
            )
        );
        $duplicate_tokens++;
    }
}


header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo "DELETED {$duplicate_tokens} Duplicate TOKENS FROM THE DATABASE. <br />";
echo "TOKEN CLEAN DONE! REMOVED {$bad_tokens} BAD TOKENS FROM THE DATABASE.";
exit;
```

Comment: Can you give me more information about this? I'm really confused right now. I'm sorry if i'm not that familiar with sql.

Comment: When I did this, it deleted all the tokens in the table.

Comment: Hmm it worked on my test table, i'll try to implement it on my live table now. Thanks!

Comment: bro I forgot to ask, does this only delete the duplicates or even the original ones? Because I forgot to say 1 copy must remain and delete only the duplicate. Thanks a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit this,

the `WHERE token = :token`is enough to delete all row with this token value.

Comment: It's only deleting bad and expired tokens but not the duplicate values.